# Missing entries in manifest.json

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I could not find a solution either searching for issues with **CopyWebpackPlugin** nor **ManifestPlugin** through github and google.

When I build the bundles using `webpack -p` the following gets done.

- Code runs through transpilers, minify, etc. (see webpack.config.js)
- imported css assets will be emitted (**MiniCssExtractPlugin**)
- the output folder (`public/build`) is emptied (**CleanWebpackPlugin**)
- some resources from `assets/img/static` get copied to `public/build/img` (**CopyWebpackPlugin**)
- a manifest.json gets written, which works nicely with symfony's assets helper, that lets you reference the same paths no matter whether the files are served from `/build` or `localhost:8080/build` (aka production build or devserver) (**ManifestPlugin**)

This is working well.

If I watch and serve files with `webpack-dev-server -d --env.development`, the same is achieved.

But when I change some JS Code and everything gets rebuilt, the assets copied by the CopyWebpackPlugin disappear from the manifest.json lookup-file.

The files are still served from eg. `http://localhost:8080/build/img/app-logo.png`.

Does anyone have a clue which plugin this issue is related to? Or even better how to solve that problem?

I'll paste the output of a correct `manifest.json`, an uncompleted one and of my webpack.config.js below.

**correct manifest.json**

```
{
  "main.css": "http://localhost:8080/build/main.css",
  "main.js": "http://localhost:8080/build/main.bundle.js",
  "img/app-logo.png": "http://localhost:8080/build/img/app-logo.png"
}
```

**manifest.json after changing a file the first time and let devserver rebuild**

```
{
  "main.css": "http://localhost:8080/build/main.css",
  "main.js": "http://localhost:8080/build/main.bundle.js"

}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = env => {
  const dev = env && env.development;

  let publicPath = '/build/';
  if (dev) {
    publicPath = 'http://localhost:8080/build/';
  }
  return {
    entry: {
      main: './assets/js/main.js',
    },

    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'build'),
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',
      publicPath: publicPath
    },

    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            'babel-loader',
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            'css-loader'
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'url-loader',
              options: {
                context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
                name: '[path][name].[ext]',
                limit: 1024
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
                name: '[path][name].[ext]',
              }
            }
          ]
        }

      ]
    },

    devtool: dev ? 'cheap-source-map' : false,

    devServer: {
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
      }
    },

    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
      alias: {
        css: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets', 'css')
      }
    },

    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery'
      }),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "[name].css",
        chunkFilename: "[id].css"
      }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {
          from: 'assets/img/static/',
          to: 'img/',
        }
      ]),
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(
        [
          'public/build'
        ]
        ,
        {
          exclude: ['public/build/img/']
        }
      ),
      new ManifestPlugin({
        writeToFileEmit: true
      }),
    ]
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, someone had similar problems with the manifest plugin, it seems to be a bug in version 2.0.3. A workaround is resetting the `seed` option back to `{}`, in the plugin's config

```
// [...]
new ManifestPlugin({
  writeToFileEmit: true,
  seed: {}
}),
// [...]
```

And it really works, as described in this [issue](https://github.com/danethurber/webpack-manifest-plugin/issues/144) on the plugin's GitHub page.